# Proving that the differences between terms of a decreasing series of always approaches $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove this lemma, which is crucial to a separate theorem I'm trying to prove:

> Given an infinite, *strictly positive*, *strictly decreasing* sequence ($a_n$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$) of real numbers, the difference between consecutive terms approaches $0$.

I believe this is equivalent to the given sequence approaching its infimum. However, I haven't taken a single analysis class, and I'm struggling to prove it nicely. I have an incomplete proof here; please note that $\inf\{a\}$ denotes the infimum of the sequence:

> If $a_n-\inf\{a\}$ approaches $0$, then $a_n - a_{n+1} = (a_n - \inf\{a\}) - (a_{n+1} - \inf\{a\})$ clearly also approaches $0$ and we are done.
>
> If $a_n-\inf\{a\}$ does not approach $0$, this would mean that *(by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit)* there would be some $\epsilon$ which $a_n - \inf\{a\} > \epsilon$, meaning that the sequence has a lower bound of $\inf\{a\} + \epsilon$ - a clear contradiction. Thus, the only option is that $a_n - a_{n-1}$ approaches $0$. QED.

Is this proof correct? If not, why? If so, how can I improve it?

Please note that I am not looking for a complete proof, but rather guidance on how to write this proof well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bounded from below, so actually the difference between $a_m$ and $a_n$ when $m,n \rightarrow \infty$ approaches 0. In your case, the proof is simpler, by contradiction we suppose that it is greater than some $\epsilon >0$, meaning $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$|a_{n+1}-a_n| > \epsilon$$
But then 
$$a_n = ((a_n - a_{n-1}) + a_{n-1}) = ((a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}) + a_{n-2})\cdots$$
leading to (using $(a_{m+1}-a_m < -\epsilon$ - our hypothesis)
$$a_n \leq a_0 - n\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$, $a_0 < \infty$ and $a_n \geq 0$ and we can take $n$ arbitrarily large we have a contradiction.

To show this for any $m,n \rightarrow \infty$, you can do similarly, you just need to change your telescoping...

Answer (score 1):

> Given an infinite, *strictly positive*, *strictly decreasing* sequence

If you are allowed to use the rather basic property that a decreasing sequence which is bounded below has a limit $\,A\,$, then the result follows directly from:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-a_{n+1}) = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right)-\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}\right)=A-A=0$$

Comment: This is true, but I'm not assuming that it has a limit.

Comment: @AJFarmar That's not an assumption, it follows from the [Monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers) that a sequence which is decreasing and bounded below is convergent.